# Match child element text color with parent on click

Tags: javascript, css

I have the following script set up:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 var currentLink = null;
 function changeLinkColor(link){
 if(currentLink!=null){
 currentLink.style.color = link.style.color; //You may put any color you want
 }
 link.style.color = '#007DAD';
 currentLink = link;
        }
</script>
```

with the following code being affected:

```
<div class="main-content">

<h2>General</h2>

<hr noshade class="main-content-hr" />

<a href="SD-XG100.html" target="myframe" class="main-content-a" onClick="changeLinkColor(this)">
  <li class="main-content-list">
    Cover
  </li>
</a>

<a href="SD-XM140.html" target="myframe" class="main-content-a" onClick="changeLinkColor(this)">
  <li class="main-content-list">
    Diagram <p class="redalert">(Not Released)</p>
  </li>
</a>

</div>
```

At the moment, when clicked, the text changes color (awesome) but the child element is not affected (the text that says "Not Released". This text does have a color in the css).

I tried switching the "li" and "a" around and that did not work. Can the red alert style be ignored when the parent element is applied?

Any ideas or suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. `<li>` must be a child of a `<ol>` or a `<ul>`. And as far as I'm aware, there is no `<text>` element.

Comment: You are also changing the color of the clicked `a` element. If the `.redalert` class has a color value it would override the JS changes.

Comment: Whoops... Those were supposed to be <p>. Thank you.

Comment: Is there a way to affect the .redalert color values when the parent is clicked?